# Using 'po' command in Xcode 6 beta 5 Debug Selected Views

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I am using the "Debug Selected Views" feature in Xcode 6 beta 5, I set a breakpoint within my prepareForInterfaceBuilder() function.

But when I try to use the po command, it gives me an error:

```
(lldb) po almondImage
error: Error in auto-import:
Failed to load linked library swiftQuartzCore of module TrailMixKit - errors:
Looking for "@rpath/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib", error: not a string object
```

Here are the first few lines of my file (including imports):

```
//
//  TrailMixIngredientImageView.swift
//  Trailmix

import UIKit
import QuartzCore
```

If I set a breakpoint while running the app in the simulator, the po command works without error.

Comment: try print almondImage. BTW what kind of object is almondImage?

Comment: @artud2000 Clearly, it's an image of an almond. :P

Comment: Same error when using 'print'. Also I get the same error if I try to print any other variables, including String objects. Also to clarify, almondImage is a JPG image of some almonds (and should probably be renamed 'almondsImage')

Comment: hahahahaha @brimizer

Comment: did you import QuartzCore? @joel.d   

import QuartzCore

The error mentions Error in auto-import if you can paste some code of the imports you have added to your code

Comment: Yes I import QuartzCore

Comment: I'm having the issue, and it happens with any po I try to use, regardless of object type.

Comment: Same issue here. But mine is with the Metal.framework

Comment: in any case I would upgrade to the latest Xcode version

Comment: Still seeing this issue in Xcode 6.0.1

Comment: The debugger in Xcode 6 is just not up to par with what it used to be for Objective-C in Xcode 5. Updates should fix this issue eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Can't add comment but did you add the framework for QuartzCore?